# Interpret a kernel density map for pollutants

Tags: arcgis-desktop, heat-map, kernel-density

I currently have a grid of values (concentration in ug/m^3) for a certain pollutant. I then converted each grid to a point to use as an input to the Kernel density analysis tool in ArcGIS pro.

The map seems correct; however, I am not quite understanding the values of this output as seen in the figure below. It does not match the range of my data.
[image]

The maximum (from the original data was 34 ug/m^3). The data range is from 0 to 34 ug/m^3.

The settings I used are the following:

[image]

Hoping you guys could help out :) Thanks!

Comment: Do the same with population field None. Divide yours by output . Result is average within radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have not set the search radius so the tool has defaulted to a radius as specified [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/kernel-density.htm#GUID-2A9F4A90-3920-403F-895D-BA8DB36EC826).

The [help file](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-kernel-density-works.htm) provides details of how the tool works. To me the key statement is "*The density at each output raster cell is calculated by adding the values of all the kernel surfaces where they overlay the raster cell center.*"

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense now. So am I right in thinking that, within that radius, the tool takes something like a weighted average? hence why values are lowered as in my explanation above.?